# How to autodetect device name in Linux

Tags: linux, disk-encryption, device-mapper

I have an encrypted USB dongue with cryptosetup, to mount it I have to execute a script that has hardcoded (or admits it as a parameter) the device name of that dongue that previously you had to search.

I wonder is there is any way via bash scripting or even doing a miniprogram to make an autodetection of the device name, leaving the workflow something like this:

- Connect USB dongue
- Execute script
- Script searches for the device name of the dongue and mounts the device
- Cryptosetup asks for the password
- Device is mounted

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The device name should appear in `dmesg`. Try something like this:

```
dev_name="/dev/"`dmesg | perl -ne '/.+\[(.+?)\] Attached/ && do{print "$1\n"}' | tail -n 1`
```

Assuming that your USB dongle is the last device attached (hence the `tail -n1`), this should save the device name as `$dev_name`.